# Combining two node forms: is that possible?

Tags: 6, nodes, forms

I am using Drupal 6 and I got a node form for a content type. I want to alter the other content type node form inside the first one; is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [Flexifield](http://drupal.org/project/flexifield) to get 2 content types on the same form.

Like docs says:

> You define a field combination by creating a node type and adding
>   fields to it. On a different node type, you can add a flexifield, and
>   then on its configuration form, specify which node types to use as
>   items within the field.

Answer (score 1):

You may implement [hook_form_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_form_alter/6) to add some custom fields (Take a look at [FAPI](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/6)) that should represent your second type fields, and treat them in [hook_nodeapi](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_nodeapi/6) with $op presave,  (as mentioned by dobeerman).

To save the fields you previously set in your form as new or even and existing node, you may create/load a node object and save them with [node_save](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.module/function/node_save/6).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add values from 1st form to 2nd form you can use hook_nodeapi() to altering 2nd content types node.

```
function mymodule_nodeapi(&$node, $op, $a3 = NULL, $a4 = NULL){
  switch($op){
    case 'presave':
      if($node->type == MY_NODE_TYPE){
        // $other_node = node_load($other_nid);
        // or
        // $other_node = new stdClass();
        // $other_node->title = ...
        // ...
        // some code to altering other node
        // $other_node = node_submit($other_node);
        // node_save($other_node);
      }
      break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can take a look at this module http://drupal.org/project/formblock

Some details from the module's project page:

> Enables the presentation of user registration, site wide contact, or node creation forms in blocks. This is particularly useful for including forms on panels.

Or just use `drush en formblock -y`