# How can I display a node create form in a Panel pane?

Tags: panels

I'm trying to build a Panel page with two columns that are stacked side-by-side. I need the left hand column to display node/add/story, and the right hand column to display node/add/page. How can I do this?

Comment: will you be saving the at the same time ?

Comment: I hadn't thought that far ahead, but it seems that formblock.module will display both forms side by side, but as soon as the "save" button is clicked on one form the content of the other form are lost ... I suppose it is, technically, still a solution to my original question, but I don't see how it could be of much use on a production site.

Comment: i realized there was going to be a problem once i submitted the answer :) I think there will be a solution to your problem, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple solution is installing [formblock](http://drupal.org/project/formblock). But that won't allow to save the nodes at the same time.

If you dont mind programming, [this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/2122/combining-two-node-forms-is-that-possible) should be of help.

Comment: Thanks, that's useful. I'm trying to fix http://drupal.org/node/937600 so I guess I'll wait until the user who posted the issue replies so I know what the actual issue is I'm trying to fix :)